# Office (JS) Outlook addin and Exchange token authentication

Tags: exchangewebservices, office-js

My Office add-in (which runs in Outlook) uses the OfficeJS library to get a callback token for authentication against Exchange:

```
Office.context.mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync(...);
```

The token is sent to our server together with some message/attachment IDs and the server will attempt to connect to Exchange to retrieve said mail attachment. I use the [EWS java API library](https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-java-api) for this. I am getting an Unauthorized 401 HTTP error back from Exchange when trying to bind to an EmailMessage:

```
ExchangeService exchangeService = new ExchangeService();    
exchangeService.getHttpHeaders().put("Authorization", "Bearer " + callbackToken); 
exchangeService.setUrl(new URI(ewsUrl));
EmailMessage mailMessage = EmailMessage.bind(exchangeService, new ItemId(mailMessageId));
```

When tested against Office 365 it all works flawlessly. However, when running this at a client I get the HTTP 401 response. The client runs Exchange 2013 on-premise. Does Exchange 2013 on-premise even support token authentication? Is there anything that needs to be done to enable this on that version of Exchange?

Comment: getCallbackTokenAsync and using the token for EWS should on recent Exchange 2013 CUs on premise. What version is the Exchange 2013? Also there might be additional error information in the HTTP response (can be in the headers) in the response from Exchange that you can capture with a network trace.

Comment: Do you mean to say that it should *work* on recent Exchange 2013 installations? I've heard from the client is that they are running Exchange 2013 Cumulative Update 16. Is that specific enough?

Comment: Yes sorry, i meant that it should work on recent Exchange 2013 installations. Exchange 2013 Cumulative Update 16 should have the support. It would be best to get a network trace to see what's going on. For example, It's possible for Exchange 2013 to be configured to block external EWS calls.

Comment: I'm getting the following in the response from Exchange:

x-ms-diagnostics: 2000003;reason="The hostname component of the audience claim value is invalid. Expected 'exchange2013.xxxxxx.com'. Actual 'webmail.xxxxxx.com'.";error_category="invalid_resource"

The odd thing is that when I ask Outlook the Office.context.mailbox.ewsUrl I get exchange2013 but when I base64 decode the token I get from Outlook (via Office.context.mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync()) it shows me a reference to webmail. How come it's different?

Comment: Any progress so far? Does Exchange 2013 on-premise support token authentication at all? I am also facing this problem and I found a similar post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53331863/outlook-web-add-in-autentication-failure-for-on-premise-exchange