# Outlook web add-in autentication failure for on-premise exchange

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices, office-js, outlook-web-addins, ntlm-authentication

I use `Office.js`'s `getCallbackTokenAsync` to load the token to pass to the backend.

In the backend, I use `EWS` to retrieve the email data. Here is how I perform the authentication.

```
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService();
service.Url = new Uri(ewsUrl); //retrieved from getCallbackTokenAsync
service.Credentials = new OAuthCredentials(ewsToken);// retrieved from getCallbackTokenAsync
```

It works well in exchange online enviroment. However when tested in on-premise exchange server, I got this authentication error:

```
Error Message: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
Stack Trace:   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EwsHttpWebRequest.Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.IEwsHttpWebRequest.GetResponse() at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.GetEwsHttpWebResponse(IEwsHttpWebRequest request)
```

I then found this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/authentication-and-ews-in-exchange) says the Oauth2 authentication is only for exchange online. I guess I need to use this NTLM (Exchange on-premises only).

The major reason I use `EWS` instead of `Graph` or `Rest` is it supports on-premise server more naturally. So should I change the authentication here? I certainly do not want to ask user for username and password.

Comment: Similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51156765/office-js-outlook-addin-and-exchange-token-authentication#comment93575988_51156765

Comment: What version of Exchange is your on Prem Version? It would also help to have a detailed network trace of the errors to maybe see what is going on. (as the other linked post says, Exchange can be configured to reject EWS calls)

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT can you provide any information(may be a link to doc) how to configure exchange server to enable token authentication?